# Identifying the conic given some conditions.

Tags: conic-sections, hyperbolic-geometry, locus

So I have to identify the conic which represents the centre of the circle which touches another circle externally, and also touches the x axis.

Here's a link to the exact question  with the equation  of the given circle:

https://s24.postimg.org/6yrcii4r9/Screenshot_2016-04-05-00-55-09~01.png

Now the answer as told by many is that its a Parabola.

My argument  is that given the symmetric nature of the conic around both sides of the circle,  It should be a hyperbola.. It seems I am wrong somewhere,  Please help.

Comment: It would be helpful if somebody helps me to insert the picture directly rather than the link

Comment: A conic has const ratio of distance from a point. and line. We have $ x =(6+u)  \cos \theta, y= u ; $ will it a conic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fixed circle has centre $(4,4)$ and radius $6$.

The locus of the centre of the circle is actually two part-parabolas.

When the circle lies above the $x$ axis, the focus of the parabola is at the centre of the circle $(4,4)$ and the directrix is the line $y=-6$

This is because the distance from the centre of the variable circle to the point $(4,4)$ is its radius plus 6, the radius of the fixed circle, and this is equal to the distance from the centre of the variable circle to the line $y=-6$, thus satisfying the geometric definition of a parabola.

Likewise, when the centre of the variable circle is below the $x$ axis, the focus is again at $(4,4)$ and the directrix is the line $y=6$

Comment: Thanks.  Your explanation is really good. Also does that mean  that no option is appropriate?

Comment: You could say that option 4 is acceptable because the centre lies on a parabola, but not the same parabola for all possible positions

Answer (score 1):

The answer is (d) : a parabola **made of the union of 4 parabolic arcs belonging to parabolas $P_1$ and $P_2$** with a common focus $O(4,4)$ and resp. directrices with equation $y=-6$ for the arcs of parabola above the $x$ axis and $y=6$ for the arcs of parabola below the $x$ axis.

Recall about the focal def. of a parabola: it is the locus of points at equal distance from a fixed point (its focus F) and a fixed straight line (its directrix D).

The equation of circle $(C_0)$ can be put into the form

$$(x-4)^2+(y-4)^2=6^2$$

showing that its center is $C(4,4)$ and its radius is $r_0=6$.

Let us understand what happens for the upper parabola (have a look at the figure): we are looking for centers of circles $C$ that share the common property of being externally tangent to $(C_0)$ and to the $x$ axis in the upper half plane: this gives a constraint  $CO=CH$ (with $H$ the orthogonal projection of $C$ onto the straight line with equation $y=-6$) that is always fulfilled, whatever the circle with the above property .

[image]

Here is the Matlab program that has given the figure:

```
clear all;close all;hold on; axis equal
set(gcf,'color','w')
t=0:0.01:2*pi;
cer=@(a,b,r)(plot([a+r*cos(t),NaN,a+0.05*[-1,1,1,-1,-1]],...
[b+r*sin(t),NaN,b+0.05*[-1,-1,1,1,-1]],'linesmoothing','on'));
cer(4,4,6);
for r=0.25:0.25:5
    cer(4+sqrt(20*r+20),r,r)
end
for r=0.25:0.25:4
    cer(4+sqrt(4*r+20),-r,r)
end
plot([-4,18],[6,6])
plot([-4,18],[0,0])
plot([-4,18],[-6,-6])
x=-3:0.01:11;
plot(x,-0.25*(x-4).^2+5,'linesmoothing','on');
plot(x,0.05*(x-4).^2-1,'linesmoothing','on')
a=15.;b=5.;
plot([4,a,a],[4,b,-6],'linesmoothing','on');
set(gca,'defaulttextfontsize',16);
text(a,5.2,'C');text(3.2,4.1,'0');text(a+0.1,-6+0.6,'H')
```

Comment: Thanks,  the Graph is very helpful.